# Converting XML Blob in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm getting back a Blob of XML using Vue-Resource and would like to convert this into a Javascript Object Array.

```
var books = []
this.$http.get('http://someurl/books.xml')
  .then((response) => {
    this.books = response.data
    console.log(response.data)
  })
```

I would then like to be able to access for example book.title from the object array.

The console displays the XML data `(Blob {size: 4548, type: "application/xml"})` but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: is this XML or jSON you have added?

Comment: FileReader.readAsText + DOMParser.